# how to double loop array php and put them on csv

Tags: php

i want to save array to csv using loop but the result always wrong.

example :

$array1 = array("request1", "request2", "request3", "request4", "request5","request6", "request7", "request8", "request9", "request10","request11","request12");

$array2 = array("api1", "api2","api3");

i wanna result in csv like this :

request1, api1
request2, api1
request3, api1
request4, api1
request5, api1
request6, api2
request7, api2
request8, api2
request9, api2
request10, api2
request11, api3
request12, api3

My code:

```
<?php

$array1 = array("request1", "request2", "request3", "request4", "request5","request6", "request7", "request8", "request9", "request10","request11","request12");

$array2 = array("api1", "api2","api3");



foreach($array1 as $xxx){
    
    for($x = 0; $x < count($array2); $x++){
        
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
            echo $xxx.",".$array2[$x]."<br>";
        }
        
        
    };  
}

?>
```

how to loop array2 5 times like this, please help me, thank you

note :
what i want to do :

I'm actually working on a project that fetches data from api. but the api itself limits 5 per day. so i want to make api as much as possible so i can fetch unlimited data. but I'm confused how to use each api with a limit of 5 correctly

Comment: Your code doesn't produce anything like the sample, nor is it clear how the sample is supposed to be produced. I can guess for 10 and 2 values in each array, but what if the arrays have more or fewer elements?

Comment: in array1 looping as usual; but in array2 loop every array 5 times

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly have 5 elements on every api request you could do it like this:

```
if (count($array1) == count($array2) * 5) {
    $k = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++) {
        if ($i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {
            $k++;
        }
        echo $array1[$i] . ',' . $array2[$k];
    }
}
```

The first if statement checks if there are exactly 5 elements per api request.

Then use two indexes, one for $array1 ($i) and another for $array2 ($k).

Loop all elements of $array1 an if the index is divisible by 5 increase $k by one.

Comment: maybe this is not what I want, I want the result to be exactly like the data above. but thanks for wanting to help :)

Comment: Whops! I didn't have in mind that `$i % 5` returns `true` for `$i = 0`. I just edited my code. Now it should work.

Comment: this may be the correct answer if my data is the same as in the example, but my data is changing, I've changed the question above, please help again :) , I just want array2 loop 5 times

Comment: As written, my code works only if there are exact 5 elements in array1 corresponding to one element in array2. But you could omit the enclosing if statement (`if (count($array1) == count($array2) * 5)`).

Comment: omg, my code work after a week ;( , thank you so much master